# How to make Paging in React Native using Flatlist onEndReached

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

When I have an axios file like this:

```
  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: ARTICLES_URL,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    data: {
      header: {
        page: pages,
        size: 10,
        sort: 'DESC',
      },
      body: {},
    },
  }).then((response) => {
    if (response.data.header.response_code === '99') {
      dispatch(articleFetchSuccess(response.data));
      while(articleFetchSuccess(Response.data)) {
      }
    } else {
      dispatch(articleFetchFailed(response.data));
    }
  });
};
```

and I have a component file like this:

```
<div>
<FlatList
            ListHeaderComponent={(
              <View style={common.flatlistHeaderContainer}>
                <Icon name="info-outline" size={24} color={color.colorMute} />
                <Text>{` ${articleData.length} Articles Found`}</Text>
              </View>
)}
            contentContainerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 19 }}
            data={articleData}
            renderItem={this.articleCardItem}
            keyExtractor={this.articleCardItemKey}
            onEndReached={this.handlePages}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0}
          />
</div>
)
}

}
```

how I can to make page in axios can dynamic based on onEndReached from flatlist when axios and component in different file? I just found when axios and component in one file, but in my case, I have axios file and component file

and this for my API response

```
{
    "header": {
        "response_code": "99",
        "response_description": "Success"
    },
    "body": [
        {
            "id": "63026",
            "kd_art_size": "YK800100160",
            "kd_article": "YK-8001-16",
            "sku_id": "22209",
            "size": "-",
            "nama": "STELAN",
            "unit": "PCS",
            "price": "259900",
            "jenis": "-",
            "discount": "0",
            "company_code": "ESM ",
            "user_id": "Wina09",
            "date_input": "2017-02-17 16:57:54",
            "user_update": "",
            "date_update": null,
            "link_gambar": null,
            "price_putus": null,
            "hpp": "0"
        },etc
```

I already tried all course about paging but I dont understand how to implement in my case.

I hope I can solve this problem.

Comment: How is `pages` defined? is it an array of objects? Every item of `pages` is a page and on end reached you load the second `pages` item?

Comment: this for API response: https://pastebin.com/MvJpVvSa

Comment: Instead of loading pasteBin links, can you please put your code in your question in code blocks? it's hard to understand the code if i have to change page every 2 seconds

Comment: Now, what should happen onEndReached? you need to do another axios call? Or do you have all the data needed to display? Is the array inside your body response 1 page you need to show?

Comment: for now, I just use a little data from API. but when I'm not use paging, in my apps load all data and make apps need more time for load data. I just need set paging for load data

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `div` in react-native? Infact you are using `View` also ? Please make me  understand your codes.

Comment: I mean View tag on div tag

Answer (score -1):

***you may try this ***

```
<Content contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}>
```

Comment: where I can implement that?

Comment: you need to add some explanations for this

Comment: What are you trying to do?